# Check if Dictonary<string,object> exists in List<Dictionary<string,object>>?

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, .net-3.5

I have a `List` that is defined as:

```
List<Dictionary<string,object>>()
```

This `List` gets populated in a `foreach loop` and basically contains `property names and values` from `ProperyInfo`.

In another `foreach loop`, I want to iterate through properties again and check if the there is a dictionary that contains a key corresponding to a value I'm looking for.  For example:

```
foreach(var item in controls)
{
    if(item !=null && list.Contains(...)) //What do I put in here
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

}
```

`controls` is a `List<Control>` where `Control` is class with one property `Name`.  `item` refers to one `Control`.

I thought about doing `list.Contains(item.Name)`, but this obviously does not work.

Comment: So do you want to know if a given key is in any of the dictionaries in the list?  Or do you have another `Dictionary` and need to know if it has the exact same set of keyvaluepairs as a dictionary in the list, or what?  by not even showing the type of `item` it makes it a lot harder to help.

Comment: You could have a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,object>>` instead of a `List`.

Comment: @AndreCalil Or just a single `Dictionary<string, object>` with a ton of objects in it...After all, it's *designed* to scale to really large sizes.

Comment: I think you need `Dictionary<Type,Dictionary<string,object>>` instead of `List<Dictionary<string,object>>`

Comment: @Servy Oh man, yes, you're right. I just couldn't figure out what's the real question here.

Comment: @AndreCalil Neither can I.  Vote to close I guess.

Comment: @Servy - I added some detail.

Comment: @AndreCalil - Detail was added. Basically, I want to see if a Dictionary item exists in a list, but I don't have all the information, such as the key for the dictionary to check if it exists.

Comment: @Xaisoft That still doesn't answer my question.  Do you have a collection of values that you're looking to match to a whole dictionary, or do you have one key that you want to search each dictionary for?

Comment: @Xaisoft Please edit *that* into the question.

Comment: Well, then a simple Linq query will do the trick, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if the key exists in *any* of the dictionaries that you have you can do this:

```
if(list.Any(dic => dic.ContainsKey(item.Name)))
```

Comment: +1 for the *SO Q&A consulting services*, I guess.

Comment: @AndreCalil Yeah.  I was 99% sure this was the answer when I posted my first comment, but I figured I'd utilize the teaching moment to help the OP learn a bit about how to ask.  Also if this had been in the 1% and not been this simple it could have been a fun problem to try to solve.

Comment: @Servy - Sometimes when we don't understand the problem, it is difficult to put together the proper question.

Comment: @Xaisoft If you don't even know what you want to end up with then you need to figure that out before even posting.  Generally you'll know what you need to end up with, just not how to get there.  This can often be easily shown with simple example input/output.  If you showed a sample list (that could be quite small) along with one or two input values and the result, in addition to a description, it would be clear that you're providing a single key, not a collection.

Comment: @Servy, Thanks your solution worked. I will work better on my questions, I just wasn't sure if I am checking the List if it cointains a whole Dictionary object or a single value because it is a List of Dictionary objects.  Hope that wasn't confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You use a reference to the dictionary. Dictionaries are a reference type, so the list will check whether a Dictionary is contained in it or not by the reference passed.

Comment: He's asking for how to do something, not what happens when he calls `Contains` on a `List<Dictionary<...>>`.  However, due to the vagueness of the question, what he's asking how to do isn't really clear yet.

Comment: But the problem is exactly how to retrieve the reference of the dictionary. If he had it, he wouldn't need to iterate the List.

Comment: If he's going to use `Contains`, he has to have it.

Comment: @Renan Then perhaps he shouldn't be using `Contains`.  He never said that he did; that was simply his attempt at a solution.  Without knowing what the OP actually wants to end up with the question, as is, simply can't be answered.

Comment: I see no other way to check whether an item exists in a list, then, unless he wants to inherit from Dictionary<T, U> and overload the equality operator.

Comment: @Renan You simply need to understand the problem.  Once the OP has clarified it the solution [is trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16658376/1159478).